# I have a problem with a excute command npm run build for import lodash

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, lodash

[error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCrpB.png)

[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "lodash" from "C:/wamp64/www/Spendify-app/Spendify/resources/js/bootstrap.js".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
error during build:
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "lodash" from "C:/wamp64/www/Spendify-app/Spendify/resources/js/bootstrap.js".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
at viteWarn (file:///C:/wamp64/www/Spendify-app/Spendify/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-934dbc7c.js:46561:23)
at onRollupWarning (file:///C:/wamp64/www/Spendify-app/Spendify/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-934dbc7c.js:46585:9)
at onwarn (file:///C:/wamp64/www/Spendify-app/Spendify/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-934dbc7c.js:46332:13)
at Object.onwarn (file:///C:/wamp64/www/Spendify-app/Spendify/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25305:13)
at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///C:/wamp64/www/Spendify-app/Spendify/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23940:26)
at file:///C:/wamp64/www/Spendify-app/Spendify/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23900:26

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/46128